# How to use the Values from JS, instead of taking the value from the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 3 buttons like the below,

```
 <button id="b1">0</button>
 <button  id="b2">0</button>
 <button  id="b3">0</button>
```

Instead of **getting/ reading the value from the HTML, I need to store the value in the JS**.

Each buttons, on click should be **incremented by 1**, when it reaches 3, again it should become `0`.

The values [0, 1, 2, 3] should be from `JS` and not from `HTML`.

I used `switch case` to show If the value is "0" the color is "**red**", If the value is 1, the color is "**blue**", if the value is 2, the color is "**green**", If the value is 3, the color is "pink".

I tried the below code, **but the switch is not working. It displays the default line of code**.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele) {
  var v = [];
  var val = +document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML;
  var res = val >= 3 ? 0 : val + 1;
  v[ele.id] = { intVal: res };
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "cyan"];
  var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  switch (v[ele.id]) {
    case "0":
    return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "red";

    case "1":
      return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "blue";
     
     case "2":
       return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "green"; 

    default:
      return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "no";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">0</button>
 <button  id="b2">0</button>
 <button  id="b3">0</button>
```

How to make the code to work ?

I need an `array` to store the values  of (0 ,1, 2, 3).

Could someone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: `"Instead of getting/ reading the value from the HTML, I need to store the value in the JS"` - but your function is reading the HTML `var val = +document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML;`??

Comment: @Davi Can you tell why my answer was unapproved?

Comment: `switch (v[ele.id]) {` that property on `v` is an object, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the array inside the function, so it gets initialized each time you execute it. It's better to take it out the function so it can save the variables. For this case as you are summing variables is better to convert variables to Integer using `parseInt()`.

Take a look to the following snippet:

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

var v = [];

function buttonVal(ele) {
  var val = parseInt(document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML);
  var res = val >= 3 ? 0 : val + 1;
  v[ele.id] = res;
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "cyan"];
  var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
 switch (res) {
    case 0:
          document.getElementById(ele.id).style.background = randColor;
           document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = res;
           break;
    case 1:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).style.background = randColor;
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = res;
      break;
     
     case 2:
       document.getElementById(ele.id).style.background = randColor; 
        document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = res;
        break;
        
    case 3:
       document.getElementById(ele.id).style.background = randColor; 
        document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = res;
        break;    
        
    default:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "no";
      document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = res;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">0</button>
 <button  id="b2">0</button>
 <button  id="b3">0</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used v[ele.id] = { intVal: res }, definitely switch will not work with 0,1,2
Use res in switch

switch(res)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use array for that use case. You can just use `.each` and populate the index as text:

### Edit

Added an array instead of index.

```js
let btns = [0,1,2];

$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});


$('button').each(function(index,ele){
  $(ele).text( btns[index] );
});

function buttonVal(ele) {
  
  var val = $(ele).text();
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "cyan"];
  var randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  switch (val) {
    case "0":
    return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "red";

    case "1":
      return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "blue";
     
     case "2":
       return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "green"; 

    default:
      return document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML = "no";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1">0</button>
 <button  id="b2">0</button>
 <button  id="b3">0</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fixed code

Logic

- Get the button `innerHTML`
- Check the value, if its 3 make it 0, or else increment it.
- correct the colors array, so that it holds the value that you needs on each `innerHTML` value.
- Update the `style.backgroundColor` for the innerHTML value.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele) {
  var val = +document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML;
  val = val === 3 ? 0 : ++val;
  document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML =  val;
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "pink"];
  switch (val) {
    case 0:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
      break;

    case 1:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
      break;

    case 2:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
      break;

    default:
      document.getElementById(ele.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[3];
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">0</button>
<button id="b2">0</button>
<button id="b3">0</button>
```

For this particular solution you dont need to have a switch case. You could just keep your `colors` array proper. You are handling the `innerHTML` logic correctly, so just access the values from `colors` array.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  buttonVal(this);
});

function buttonVal(ele) {
  let val = +document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML;
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "pink"];
  val = val === 3 ? 0 : ++val;
  document.getElementById(ele.id).innerHTML =  val;
  document.getElementById(ele.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[val];
}
```

```html
<button id="b1">0</button>
<button id="b2">0</button>
<button id="b3">0</button>
```